# How to use the method readDataForTable?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm developing an App which uses a DataBase managed from MagicalRecord. App displays names which user can add tapping + button. + button opens an UIAlert where user can type a new name and tapping OK name is added to a DataBase.
Trouble is that, everytime user add a new name, table has to be reloaded to display new name.
To reload table I imported CoreDataHelper and I'm using this method: (I've found everything there: https://github.com/kgudger/AssignLine )

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * eventiArray; // Array which populate table
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

-(void)readDataForTable {
       _eventiArray = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsForEntity:@"Entity" withSortKey:@"nomeEvento" andSortAscending:YES andContext: _managedObjectContext];
       [self.tableView reloadData]; }

// (Entity is the name of NSManagedObject SubClass)
// (nomeEvento is the name of NSString in NSManagedObject SubClass)
```

Running, it crashes saying `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Entity''` but I can't understand the reason, can somebody help me? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use MagicalRecord to load the data.

```
-(void)readDataForTable {
       self.eventiArray = [YourEntity MR_findAllSortedBy:@"nomeEvento" ascending:YES inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
       [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If you want to use it in context

```
[YourEntity MR_findAllSortedBy:@"nomeEvento" ascending:YES inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

or

```
[YourEntity MR_findAllSortedBy:@"nomeEvento" ascending:YES];
```

Comment: @Matte.Car I just updated my answer for you. your context is probably null, so either use the default or leave it blank and don't use in context. What error are you getting?

Comment: Your last proposal is better, it generate a different kind of crash! Now app crash due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath nomeEnvento not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Entity id=1>' , it should means that now it recognize Entity but it don't recognize the object in Entity...

Comment: @Matte.Car make sure in your NSSQLEntity.h file that you have `nomeEnvento`. If not then from your .xmodel file select the NSSQLEntity entity and from the top nav bar select Editor -> Create NSManagedObject

Comment: Great Man!! last error was generate simply from a bad copy-paste; "nomeEvento" became "nomeEnvento", I didn't saw it and it generated mistake, so _eventiArray = [Entity MR_findAllSortedBy:@"nomeEvento" ascending:YES inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]]; is correct and works!!! Thank you so much!!! (corrected now!)